# Deploy win Server 2003 as secondary DC in virtual Server 2008 R2 AD environmen

Tags: active-directory

We have 3 blade servers in which I am planning to install the virtual infrastructure.
In blade 1 I plan to install Virtual DC which will be migrated from win 2003 DC to win 2008 R2, than file server will be migrated and DFS installed. I will include here also Virtual Print server, virtual Wsus server, Virtual Spiceworks server.

In two other blades I am planing to install a fail over clustering feature and put SQL 2008 server, Sharepoint 2010 Server, Email server and a server for backup and testing purposes.

Since I read a lot of recommendations that Clusters need a separate domain in order to be authenticated, and they need a physical DC .

My question is can I add e second domain controller in win 2003 with a different domain name which will be the demoted physical DC in win 2003 just for cluster authentication. 
I will reinstall the win 2003 operating system and than add it as a second domain controller. 
Is this OK. Did anybody tried this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Clusters do not need to be in a separate domain.
Clusters do not require physical DCs.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need it to use the same domain if you want it to be a secondary DC, and you'll need to make sure your 2008 R2 DC is only running at the 2003 functional level.